# Extract data from html to csv using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I want to extract data from a weather site and copy it to a csv file for further analysis. I am using python and BeautifulSoup. I have been struggling in order to get the affected cities from the weather report and the values. 
Hier is how the HTML looks like:

```
> <html>  <head>   <meta charset="utf-8"/>  </head>  <body>   <div
> id="main">    <div id="wettertab">
>     <p>
>      <strong>
>       Letzte Aktualisierung: Do, 10. Aug, 18:41 Uhr
>      </strong>
>     </p>
>     <h1 id="Hessen">
>      Hessen
>     </h1>
>     <h2 id="Gemeinde Aarbergen">
>      Gemeinde Aarbergen
>     </h2>
>     <table>
>      <colgroup>
>       <col <="" class="firstColumn" col=""/>
>       <col class="colorColumn"/>
>       <col class="colorColumn"/>
>       <col class="colorColumn"/>
>       <thead>
>        <tr>
>         <th>
>          Schlagzeile
>         </th>
>         <th>
>          Gültig von
>         </th>
>         <th>
>          Gültig bis
>         </th>
>         <th>
>          Beschreibung
>         </th>
>        </tr>
>       </thead>
>       <tr>
>        <td>
>         Amtliche WARNUNG vor DAUERREGEN
>        </td>
>        <td>
>         Do, 10. Aug, 12:00 Uhr
>        </td>
>        <td>
>         Sa, 12. Aug, 06:00 Uhr
>        </td>
>        <td>
>         Es tritt Dauerregen mit Unterbrechungen auf. Dabei werden Niederschlagsmengen zwischen 40 l/m² und 60 l/m² erwartet.
>        </td>
>       </tr>
>      </colgroup>
>     </table>
```

There are four values from the tables that I need:

```
<tr> 
<td> Amtliche WARNUNG vor DAUERREGEN 
</td> 
<td> Do, 10. Aug, 12:00 Uhr 
</td> 
<td> Sa, 12. Aug, 06:00 Uhr 
</td> 
<td> Es tritt Dauerregen mit Unterbrechungen auf. Dabei werden Niederschlagsmengen zwischen 40 l/m² und 60 l/m² erwartet. 
</td> 
</tr>
```

And I also need the name of the place:

```
<h2 id="Gemeinde Aarbergen">
 Gemeinde Aarbergen
</h2>
```

The HTML tag for "h2" is always before the table but it dosen't belong to the table itself, as I can see.

This is my code snippet until now:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = urlopen("html_warnung.html")
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

table = soup.findAll("table")
for div in table:
    row = ''
    rows = div.findAll('td')

    for row in rows:
        print(row.text)
```

Now I can print the values from the tables, and I can also get the city name by:

```
gemeinde_list = []
for gemeinde in soup.findAll('h2'):
    gemeinde_list.append(gemeinde.get("id"))
```

What would be the best way to export all the infos togehter to  csv-file, in order to have separeted values:

Gemeinde Aarbergen
Amtliche WARNUNG vor DAUERREGEN
Do, 10. Aug, 12:00 Uhr
Sa, 12. Aug, 06:00 Uhr
Es tritt Dauerregen wechselnder Intensität auf. Dabei werden Niederschlagsmengen zwischen 35 l/m² und 50 l/m² erwartet. In Staulagen werden Mengen bis 70 l/m² erreicht.

I am using Python 3.6
Please some help.

Comment: You can use the csv module that comes with Python.

Comment: Hi Mekicha, yes I guess the hard part is how to put together the values from the html file, and when I get those together, may be as a list, I think I will be able to store them in a csv. My problem at the moment is to the values as described.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since neither the table or heading have any characteristic attributes, you can use the `find_next_siblings` / `find_previous_siblings` methods to get neighbouring tags.

```
tables = soup.find_all('table')
data = []
for table in tables: 
    previous = table.find_previous_siblings('h2') 
    id = previous[0].get('id') if previous else None
    rows = [td.get_text(strip=True) for td in table.find_all('td')]
    data.append([id] + rows)
```

The `data` variable is a nested list which you can now write to csv.

```
with open('my_file.csv', 'wb') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerows(data)
```

Comment: It looks like the whole thing is within a div. So if you have multiple of those on each page, make the main element the div-tag. So all you need to do - for each div - is grabbing the .h2 and all .text from the tds in the second tr.

Comment: @jlaur we don't know the exact structure of the html so i tried a more generic solution: "find all tables and the previous 'h2'". However your idea: "find all divs that contain at least one 'h2' and 'table'" may work as well or even better. Nice!

Comment: @t.m.adam: that did the job, very elegant. Thanks. There is only one div in earch page, the html code is actually very simple, there is only one div and many tables.

Comment: I know realize that a have a list of lists. How can I get the first items of the lists to be compared to other list in other files??

Comment: You can use `[i[0] for i in data]` to select the first item of all lists in `data`. If you want to read the `data` list from file use: `with open('my_file.csv', 'rb') as f: data = list(csv.reader(f))`

Comment: @t.m.adam, thanks for the comment, it work. Last comment from me, I have following date format in my data set Di, 15. Aug, 21:52 Uhr. How can convert this to a legible date format in pandas. I want to compare if the actual date match the proposed date from my data-set. Should I create a new question, or is this ok here?

Comment: You could use `pd.to_datetime`, but i have no idea how you would format this string. Sorry, i can't help you with that.

Answer (score 0):

You can put the data you want to save in a csv row into a tuple. Basically, assign them to a variable while you are extracting them and put all of them into a tuple.
I do not fully understand the structure of the data you are extracting.

But I guess:

```
city_name = "Gemeinde Aarbergen"
start_date = "Do, 10. Aug, 12:00 Uhr"
end_date = "Sa, 12. Aug, 06:00 Uhr"
desc = "Es tritt Dauerregen wechselnder Intensität auf. Dabei werden Niederschlagsmengen zwischen 35 l/m² und 50 l/m² erwartet. In Staulagen werden Mengen bis 70 l/m² erreicht."
```

As I said I dont know what the fields are. you can name them better.
Then you will have:

```
import csv
csv_row = (city_name, start_date, end_date, desc)
with open(filename, "wb") as csv_file:
    writer = csv.writer(csv_file, delimiter=',')
    writer.writerow(csv_row)
```

Hope this makes sense.

Comment: The structure is correct. My problem is how to extract the data in that format from the html. As you can see in the HTML example above, the name of the city <h2 id="Gemeinde Aarbergen"> is outside of the table, I don't know to match the city with each table.

Comment: Extract the city and save it as city_name, then parse the table and extract the other variables you need, saving them as well. And then create the tuple. Or do the rows repeat? Meaning, there's more than one table for each city name for example?

Comment: You can check to see if there is a div that contains the h2 and the table for each weather entry or you can see if there is a h2 element for each table. You can `findAll h2` and `tables` . You get two lists in that case for h2 and tables. You can loop through both to create the tuple or use `zip`. Let me know if this does not help