# Export data from BeautifulSoup to CSV

Tags: python-2.7, parsing, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, export-to-csv

[DISCLAIMER] I have been through plenty of the other answers on the area, but they do not seem to work for me.

I want to be able to export the data I have scraped as a CSV file.

My question is how do I write the piece of code which outputs the data to a CSV?

**Current Code**

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 

url = "http://implementconsultinggroup.com/career/#/6257"
r = requests.get(url)

req = requests.get(url).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)
links = soup.find_all("a")

for link in links:
     if "career" in link.get("href") and 'COPENHAGEN' in link.text:
             print "<a href='%s'>%s</a>" %(link.get("href"), link.text)
```

**Output from the code**

```
View Position

</a>
<a href='/career/management-consultants-to-help-our-customers-succeed-with-
it/'>
Management consultants to help our customers succeed with IT
COPENHAGEN • At Implement Consulting Group, we wish to make a difference in 
the consulting industry, because we believe that the ability to create Change 
with Impact is a precondition for success in an increasingly global and 
turbulent world.




View Position

</a>
<a href='/career/management-consultants-within-process-improvement/'>
Management consultants within process improvement
COPENHAGEN • We are looking for consultants with profound
experience in Six Sigma, Lean and operational
management
```

**Code I have tried**

```
with open('ImplementTest1.csv',"w") as csv_file:
     writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
     writer.writerow(["link.get", "link.text"])
     csv_file.close()
```

**Output in CSV format**

Column 1: Url Links

Column 2: Job description

E.g

Column 1: /career/management-consultants-to-help-our-customers-succeed-with-
    it/

Column 2: Management consultants to help our customers succeed with IT
    COPENHAGEN • At Implement Consulting Group, we wish to make a difference in 
    the consulting industry, because we believe that the ability to create Change 
    with Impact is a precondition for success in an increasingly global and 
    turbulent world.

Comment: You have to store your results in a list.

Comment: Thanks Adam. I'm quite new to Python, are you able to quickly show how to create/store the results as a list?

Comment: Here is my answer to a similar question: [extract-data-from-html-to-csv-using-beautifulsoup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45675705/extract-data-from-html-to-csv-using-beautifulsoup/45676970#45676970)

Comment: So I just have to add in this piece? 

tables = soup.find_all('table')
data = []
for table in tables: 
    previous = table.find_previous_siblings('h2') 
    id = previous[0].get('id') if previous else None
    rows = [td.get_text(strip=True) for td in table.find_all('td')]
    data.append([id] + rows)

Comment: Or which parts of the code you wrote is relevant in my case?

Comment: The parts that collect the data and write it to csv. Just use Shahin's answer.

Comment: Sir t.m.adam, please take a look into the link. Sometimes you provide some answer on some complicated stuff which is out of the box and hard to find anywhere, as in .tail.strip() in css selector. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46028354/unable-to-get-the-full-content-using-selector

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this script and get the csv output:

```
import csv ; import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 

outfile = open('career.csv','w', newline='')
writer = csv.writer(outfile)
writer.writerow(["job_link", "job_desc"])

res = requests.get("http://implementconsultinggroup.com/career/#/6257").text
soup = BeautifulSoup(res,"lxml")
links = soup.find_all("a")

for link in links:
     if "career" in link.get("href") and 'COPENHAGEN' in link.text:
        item_link = link.get("href").strip()
        item_text = link.text.replace("View Position","").strip()
        writer.writerow([item_link, item_text])
        print(item_link, item_text)
outfile.close()
```

Comment: Thanks Shahin - this works exactly as I wanted it. The only feature not working it the last piece: outfile.close(): 

  File "<stdin>", line 7
    outfile.close()
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: This is because I suppose, you use python 2 whereas I use python 3. I'm not sure, though! However, it runs flawless in my end.